# Установка WordPress на разные сайты

Tags: wordpress, установка

Судя по https://ipipe.ru/info/ustanovka-wordpress-na-openserver, пришел к выводу, что wordpress устанавливается на разные сайты отдельно для каждого сайта, т.е. в каждой из папок (для всех сайтов) должны быть файлы из папки wordpress. Если это не так, то приведите пожалуйста страницу, на которой объясняется единоразовая установка для всех сайтов одновременно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, именно так. Для каждого сайта должны быть свои папки WordPress. Например:

```
D:\Sites\test - содержит все файлы WP
D:\Sites\mysite - содержит все файлы WP
```

и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Один сайт, один WP. Ты можешь сделать мультисайт, и отдавать разные базы данных для одной и той же темы WP... но это будет одна и та же CMS

Comment: В мультисайте одна база на все сайты.

Answer (score 0):

> Если это не так, то приведите пожалуйста страницу, на которой
> объясняется единоразовая установка для всех сайтов одновременно.

Одну установку ВордПресс-а для множества сайтов можно осуществить 2мя способами.

1. Установить ВП в режиме сети сайтов. Иначе - мультисайта.
   Подробнее см в документации: https://codex.wordpress.org/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8
2. Используя алиасы.
   Для этого в ПУ хостинга указать все нужные алиасы домена, а в конфиге прописать префикс таблиц подобным образом:

```
$prefix = str_replace( array( 'www.', '-', '.' ), '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
$table_prefix = $prefix . '_';
```

Оба способа имеют свои недостатки, и в общем случае я бы рекомендовал использовать отдельные установки ВП на каждый домен.